# codeEntityReference linkText not working

Tags: sandcastle, maml

I'm following Sandcastle's MAML guide to link to documentation pages within my help file ([exact page I'm referencing](https://ewsoftware.github.io/MAMLGuide/html/bc490dbf-7d46-432d-a816-3ae16ab6af54.htm)).
The problem I am having is that the `linkText` attribute does not seem to be taken into account even though I'm using it in an identical way to the guide (I've even copy/pasted the example code and it isn't doing what it claims it should).
I have a couple sections within my document like so:

```
<section>
  <title>Common Methods and Properties of MyClass</title>
  <content>
    <para>
      For a list of all members of this type, see
      <codeEntityReference linkText="MyClass Members">
        AllMembers.T:X.Y.Z.MyClass
      </codeEntityReference>
    </para>
  </content>
</section>
<relatedTopics>
  <codeEntityReference linkText="MyClass Members">AllMembers.T:X.Y.Z.MyClass</codeEntityReference>
  <codeEntityReference>T:X.Y.Z.MyClass</codeEntityReference>
</relatedTopics>
```

I can confirm that the links work correctly and each will bring me to the desired page, they just display in an undesired way.

Both of the `codeEntityReference` lines with a linkText should display the text. But instead, all of the `codeEntityReference` links display as "MyClass" even though one link to the class page, and the other links to the members page. It is a little confusing...